# How can i Fix my media players?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, qt, mplayer

I always face a problem with media application that depend on qt and MPlayer it happen when I run my device for a long time I see error.
This is photo in Linux mint 17.2 
 [image: picture 1]
 
and [Last question the same error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699901/whats-happen-to-my-application-ubuntu-14-04-lts) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
this happen with "Smplayer , VLC , clementine , ultra copier" for all user also for guest session 
it's fixed if i restart system or reopen smplayer from terminal , i read a some documents of how to restart smplayer after period of time and this useless .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. What other programs are affected? What happens if you launch `smplayer` from a terminal? What error messages do you get? When did this start happening? Does it affect different distributions? Why are you tagging with Ubuntu *and* Mint? Does it only affect your user or does it happen  to all users?

Comment: @terdon i don't know what's program affect it happen only when i run disro for more than 5 hour when i run it from terminal every thing return back i think program restart again i can't see any error message i only see this photo

Comment: Does it only happen with smplayer or with other programs also? try opening a terminal and running `smplayer`. That should give you better error messages.

Comment: @terdon it happen with all qt program when i open terminal i don't see any error message it's simply restart qt and all program return back

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and give the names of other programs with  this problem. Also, try creating a new user and testing. Does the new user also have the problem?

Comment: @terdon yes it happen for all users until i restart or open from terminal

Comment: @terdon it also happen with guest user

Comment: please [EDIT]  your question and add the things you said in the comments.

Comment: @terdon i read some document of how to restart smplayer after period of time i try it and nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching for a long time i found a great solution by append

```
env "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"
```

to Exec .desktop path

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)